Angular Google Auth. - Resizing and using white different background-color
i m currently writing my own little web app and wanted to implement google auth. services. i m following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EO-U01u9vFQ
while loading the page, the google sign in button first looks how i want it to be, but after a fraction of a second it suddenly resizes, sets its own background to white and gets aligned to the left... hope someone can help me with this!
following the two images:

First few moments on the login page


2.

renderButton (welcome.ts)
google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById("google-sign-in-button"), {           
  theme: 'filled_black',
  size: 'large',
  shape: 'circle',
  width: '100%',
  logo_alignment: 'center',
  text: 'signin_with',
  locale: "en-US"
});

GetStarted (welcome.component.html)
<h2>Get Started</h2>
<div style="margin-left: 2rem; margin-right: 2rem; justify-content: center;" id="google-sign-in-button">
  <div style="justify-content: center;" id="google-sign-in-button"></div>
</div>

i expect the button to stay like in picture 1. for the whole time, and not change its shape, color and size.
i tried setting the background color, width and the content alignment manually, but nothing seems to work.

What version of Angular are you using? You have tagged this post with angularjs which is only for the legacy framework.
